# how can i melt a data.table with concatenated column names

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using dcast.data.table to convert a long data.table to a wide data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1234)
dt.base <- data.table(A = rep(c(1:3),2), B = rep(c(1:2),3), C=c(1:4,1,2),thevalue=rnorm(6))


#from long to wide using dcast.data.table()
dt.cast <- dcast.data.table(dt.base, A ~ B + C, value.var = "thevalue", fun = sum)

#now some stuff happens e.g., please do not bother what happens between dcast and melt
setkey(dt.cast, A)
dt.cast[2, c(2,3,4):=1,with = FALSE]
```

now i want to melt the data.table back again to the original column layout and here i'm stuck, how do I separate the concatenated columnames from the casted data.table, this is my problem

```
dt.melt <- melt(dt.cast,id.vars = c("A"), value.name = "thevalue")
```

I need two columns instead of one

the result that i'm looking for can be produced with this code

```
#update
dt.base[A==2 & B == 1 & C == 1, thevalue :=1]
dt.base[A==2 & B == 2 & C == 2, thevalue :=1]

#insert (2,1,3 was not there in the base data.table)
dt.newrow <- data.table(A=2, B=1, C=3, thevalue = 1)
dt.base <-rbindlist(list(dt.base, dt.newrow))
dt.base
```

As always any help is appreciated

Comment: It is not clear what you would like the end result to look like.  Can you please show the desired output.  Presumably, couldnt you just splice the `variable` column of `dt.melt`?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I added some additional code, to produce the result that I'm looking for. But in the meantime there is good solution from David, now I'm just wandering if this can be directly achieved from within the melt-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
colnames <- c("B", "C")
dt.melt[, (colnames) := (colsplit(variable, "_", colnames))][, variable := NULL]
subset(dt.melt, thevalue != 0)
# or dt.melt[thevalue != 0, ]

#   A   thevalue B C
#1: 1 -1.2070657 1 1
#2: 2  1.0000000 1 1
#3: 2  1.0000000 1 3
#4: 3  1.0844412 1 3
#5: 2  1.0000000 2 2
#6: 3  0.5060559 2 2
#7: 1 -2.3456977 2 4
```

If your data set isn't representable and there could be zeros in valid rows, here's alternative approach

```
colnames <- c("B", "C")
setkey(dt.melt[, (colnames) := (colsplit(variable, "_",colnames))][, variable := NULL], A, B, C)
setkey(dt.base, A, B, C)
dt.base <- dt.melt[rbind(dt.base, data.table(A = 2, B = 1, C = 3), fill = T)]
dt.base[, thevalue.1 := NULL]

##    A B C   thevalue
## 1: 1 1 1 -1.2070657
## 2: 1 2 4 -2.3456977
## 3: 2 1 1  1.0000000
## 4: 2 2 2  1.0000000
## 5: 3 1 3  1.0844412
## 6: 3 2 2  0.5060559
## 7: 2 1 3  1.0000000
```

**Edit**

As. suggested by @Arun, the most efficient way would be to use  @AnandaMahto [cSplit](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) function, as it is using `data.table` too, i.e,

```
cSplit(dt.melt, "variable", "_")
```

**Second Edit**

In order to save the manual merges, you can set `fill = NA` (for example) while dcasting and then do everything in one go with `csplit`, e.g.

```
dt.cast <- dcast.data.table(dt.base, A ~ B + C, value.var = "thevalue", fun = sum, fill = NA)
setkey(dt.cast, A)
dt.cast[2, c(2,3,4):=1,with = FALSE]
dt.melt <- melt(dt.cast,id.vars = c("A"), value.name = "thevalue")
dt.cast <- cSplit(dt.melt, "variable", "_")[!is.na(thevalue)]
setnames(dt.cast, 3:4, c("B","C"))

#    A   thevalue B C
# 1: 1 -1.2070657 1 1
# 2: 2  1.0000000 1 1
# 3: 2  1.0000000 1 3
# 4: 3  1.0844412 1 3
# 5: 2  1.0000000 2 2
# 6: 3  0.5060559 2 2
# 7: 1 -2.3456977 2 4
```

Comment: Hey David, this is exactly what I'm looking for, great, I have to check how it scales, once again I realize that I'm biased by what I was doing minutes ago ... using dcast made me think I have to use melt, funny! I will wait some hours if there is a "native" melt answer before accepting your answer

Comment: A little more complex than that to avoid removing originally existing zero values :-) it was more the colsplit thing :-)

Comment: regretfully, `colsplit` will not scale well.  Try using `unlist(strsplit(x, "_"))` instead

Comment: Hey David, my final dataset has seven rowsj 6 from the orignal dataset and one from the insert (A=2,B=1, C=4), but that is not the problem, I was stuck with the colsplit or mysterios unlist(strsplit(()) :-)

Comment: Try the `cSplit` function from @AnandaMahto. You can get it [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733).

Comment: @Arun, you are right. Wonder how I didn't think of it as it was already sourced on my machine...

Comment: So I did some checks, finally I decided to use the cSplit function!

Comment: @DavidArenburg Hmmm, I'm not sure if I should accept your answer basically you set the things in motion but it seems that cSplit scales better, I assume it is due to the strSplit thing, but I also want that my gets its answer sign ...

Comment: @TomMartens, I've came up with your desired output, what else do you need?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you very much for your time, I just realized that there was a typo in my previous comment, the word question was missing, so once again thanks!

Comment: @TomMartens, see my last edit re setting `fill = NA` and the using `cSplit`. I think this would be the best way of doing it